# SQL error when trying to move Joomla site to new account

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a website that I am attempting to move from a "traditional" hosting account with GoDaddy to a new "cpanel" hosting account. The reason for the move is that we would like to be able to sell MP3s from the site and in order to place these files in the home directory we need a cpanel account (according to GoDaddy).

We use Akeeba backup and admin tools religiously and have never had any problem with each of these programs...

I moved a copy of the site to a friend's testing environment (different host) using Akeeba kickstart and no problem. However, after moving the archive file and kickstart file to the new cpanel account on GoDaddy, I get a database restoration error (after making it through the pre-installation screen) and have reached out to support both GoDadddy and Akeeba (which is fantastic, but they are closed for the weekend).

So here are the steps I've taken to try and fix this and the results:

1. Created the database, DB user, and associated them in cpanel on
   the new GoDaddy hosting account.
2. Uploaded kickstart.php file and the akeeba backup archive (.jpa
   file).
3. Initialized kickstart by going to the URL and made it through the
   pre-installation page

Next I get the following error:

> An error occurred while restoring the database. The error message can
>   be found below. Click on the × button at the top right of this dialog
>   message to close it and return to the database restoration page.
>
> SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `xxxx_usergroups`

NOTE: Though always a SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM error sometimes the table is different

Here are the additional things I've tried to date:

1. Completely wiped out site and began the process again with kickstart
   file and archive file - result: still get error
2. Wiped out site, changed php version from 5.4 to 5.3 and began
   process again with kickstart file and archive file - result still
   get error
3. Created a new DB user in cpanel to make sure that user has full
   privileges on database, associated this user to the DB, and began
   process again with kickstart file and archive file: - result: still
   get error
4. Searched web and Akeeba site for other possible fixes - result: was
   not able to discover anything else that would help

Akeeba had asked me to see if GoDaddy has a maximum query limit per hour/minute. GoDaddy does; 1000. And according to GoDaddy they only way for me to change this is through a php.ini file but aside from that they are not able to help.

I have never created a php.ini file and have no idea what code needs to be added to that file to fix this issue. I have looked at resources online for PHP but as this is not my specialty I'm completely lost when trying to figure out which commands are needed in this ini file. And again, Akeeba is closed for the weekend so I'm hoping to get some help before then.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your cPanel you should have a php configuration icon under the sofware/services, if you are allowed to edit your own php configuration. From there you will want to change MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR to what ever you need.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get in there and see a list of settings I'm allowed to change, but I can't make the changes by clicking on that icon. I need to set them in a php.ini file and I'm not sure which of those codes I need to use - if not a combination of them.

Here is the list: 
register_globals, 
file_uploads, 
upload_max_filesize, 
asp_tags, 
safe_mode, 
include_path, 
max_execution_time, 
max_input_time, 
memory_limit, 
session.save_path